# dplyr bind_rows mutate types to match

Tags: r, dplyr

Say i have two simple data frames like so:

```
stuff <- data.frame('a', 'b')
col1 <- c(1,2,3)
stuff <- data.frame(col1)
col1 <- c('1','2', '3')
stuff2 <- data.frame(col1)
```

I want to merge them into one data frame, and trying to use `dplyr`'s `bind_rows`, e.g. like so:

```
bind_rows(stuff, stuff2)
```

But (unsurprisingly) i am getting

> Error in bind_rows_(x, .id) : 
>     Column `col1` can't be converted from numeric to factor

Is there a way for me to tell `bind_rows` to mutate the rows to the target (or try to)?

Comment: There is a type issue.  Do you need something like `list(stuff, stuff2) %>% map_df( ~ .x %>% mutate(col1 = as.numeric(as.character(col1))))`

Comment: @akrun yes except i don't want to spell out all my columns, i have hundreds of them; and in some the mismatch is one way and in the others mismatch is the other... so i want the types to be worked out automatically

Comment: I guess you need `stuff %>% mutate_all(funs(type.convert(as.character(.), as.is = TRUE)))` i.e. if we have a list of data.frames, then use `map` as above i.e. `list(stuff, stuff2) %>% map_df( ~ .x %>% mutate_all(funs(type.convert(as.character(.), as.is = TRUE))))`

Comment: @akrun but what if i have a mix of columns? some are characters, some are numerical etc.

Comment: then it becomes difficult because it is a decision you have to provide manually

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use data.table's rbindlist...
since this function requires a list as input, you will automatically lose the character-factor issue...

rbindlist also has some functions that make life easier (and it is also very fast!)

```
#lets make'a named list
l <- list( stuff = stuff, stuff2 = stuff2 ) 
#now bind the two df's together
library(data.table)
rbindlist( l, use.names = TRUE )
#    col1
# 1:    1
# 2:    2
# 3:    3
# 4:    1
# 5:    2
# 6:    3
```

The better stuff comes out when you want a little more functionality... let's say you want to know which data is coming from which df... here the names list comes into play

```
rbindlist( l, use.names = TRUE, idcol = TRUE )
#      .id col1
#1:  stuff    1
#2:  stuff    2
#3:  stuff    3
#4: stuff2    1
#5: stuff2    2
#6: stuff2    3
```

Or, when not all colnames are present in all df's:

```
col2 <- c('1','2', '3')
stuff2 <- data.frame(col2)
rbindlist( l, use.names = TRUE, fill = TRUE, idcol = "origin" )
#    origin col1 col2
# 1:  stuff    1 <NA>
# 2:  stuff    2 <NA>
# 3:  stuff    3 <NA>
# 4: stuff2   NA    1
# 5: stuff2   NA    2
# 6: stuff2   NA    3
```

If columnnames are not the same, but you still want to put both df's into one column:

```
col1 <- c(1,2,3)
stuff <- data.frame(col1)
col2 <- c('1','2', '3')
stuff2 <- data.frame(col2)
#create a named list
l <- list(stuff = stuff, stuff2 = stuff2) 
rbindlist( l )

#    col1
# 1:    1
# 2:    2
# 3:    3
# 4:    1
# 5:    2
# 6:    3
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try using `rbind(...)` both data.frames have got same number of columns with same name.

```
rbind(stuff, stuff2, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

#   col1
# 1    1
# 2    2
# 3    3
# 4    1
# 5    2
# 6    3
```

**Option#2:** If column names are not same

One can try using auto coercing power of `c(...)`. The documentation for that function suggests as:

> ```
> All arguments are coerced to a common type which is the type of the returned value,
> and all attributes except names are removed
> ```

Now, if all the both `data.frames` got same number of columns and in same order then you can try as:

```
library(purrr)

map2_df(stuff, stuff2, c)

# # A tibble: 6 x 1
#    col1
#   <dbl>
# 1  1.00
# 2  2.00
# 3  3.00
# 4  1.00
# 5  2.00
# 6  3.00
```

**Note:** Please make sure that all `factor` type columns are converted to `character` type before applying above code to avoid unexpected results.

**Data:**

```
col1 <- c(1,2,3)
stuff <- data.frame(col1)
col1 <- c('1','2', '3')
stuff2 <- data.frame(col1)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have mixed data types try this:

```
#data
stuff <- data.frame('a', 'b')
col1 <- c(1,2,3)
stuff <- data.frame(col1)
col1 <- c('1','2', '3')
stuff2 <- data.frame(col1)
#for loop to convert classes from one df to the other
for (x in colnames(stuff)) {
  stuff[,x] <- eval(call( paste0("as.", class(stuff2[,x])), stuff[,x]) )}
#bind_rows
bind_rows(stuff,stuff2)
```